# Laravel Homestead is stuck at running npm install

Tags: laravel, npm, vagrant, homestead

I've installed Laravel Homestead recently, but when I try to run `npm install` it gets stuck at building the babel package.

Line where it get's stuck: `build:@babel/helper-validator-option: sill linkStuff @babel/helper-validator-option@7.12.11 has /home/vagrant/code/testsite/node_modules as its parent node_modules`

Installing a single package like VueJS works fine.

I'm using NFS on Windows right now for syncing the folders.

Versions:

- Vagrant: 2.2.14
- Homestead: 10.1.1
- Windows 10

Kind Regards,

Corné

Comment: Where are you running this command from? Inside your virtual machine? I personally always had issues with running it inside the virtual machine, so I always run it on windows.

Comment: @Remul I'm running this from my virtual machine indeed, I'll try it from my host OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your Office wifi. Your office Network is blocking your proxy. That is why you are stuck.

Switch to another Wifi and maybe connect your VPN(if you are doing it on your office computer)

Comment: I'm currently at my home wifi, if I try to install a single package that works fine.